# From imports doesn't work on linux

Tags: python, import

I have probably path inaccuracies but can't track it. I have a following statement:

```
from serial import SerialException
# from Utilities.UnitsFormat import UnitsFormat
from Loggers.MainLogger import NetworkLogger as Logger
import Utilities.Serial.SerialHandle.SerialHandle as SH
```

It works well on Windows buy fails to find path in Debian Linux:

```
> root@debian-armhf:/# cd usr/CROW/ATE/Drivers/PSU_PR_V2/
root@debian-armhf:/usr/CROW/ATE/Drivers/PSU_PR_V2# python PSU_PR.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PSU_PR.py", line 79, in <module>
    from Loggers.MainLogger import NetworkLogger as Logger
ImportError: No module named Loggers.MainLogger
root@debian-armhf:/usr/CROW/ATE/Drivers/PSU_PR_V2#
```

How can I resolve this while I remain simple with path management and support both operating systems?
I have tried this with no help:

```
import os
if os.name == 'nt':
    sys.path.append("C:\CROW\ATE")
else:
    sys.path.append("usr/CROW/ATE")
```

Comment: Can you show the directory structure? Do you have a `Loggers` directory, and does it have a `MainLogger` subdirectory with a `__init__.py` in it?

Comment: what does your sys.path look like on each system?

Comment: In windows it looks like:
C:\CROW\ATE\ and all the projects under
In linux the structure is the same:
/usr/CROW/ATE and all projects under
__init__.py is in each package, the code works under Windows.

Comment: Logger is found under:
"C:\CROW\ATE\Loggers\MainLogger.py"

Comment: Your directory is lacking an initial `/`: `sys.path.append("/usr/CROW/ATE")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the file you are manipulating the path from is located some where under the `CROW/ATE` directory.  You could use this code to get a system independent path to that directory like so:

```
import re
import os

def get_project_dir():
    return re.findall(''.join(['.*', os.path.join('CROW', 'ATE')]), os.path.abspath(__file__))[0]
```

and then do

```
sys.path.append(get_project_dir())
```

**I wasn't able to test this on windows but this should be close.*